# google apps script to paste row based on dependent drop down list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, dependencies

I have created a google sheet with a dependent drop down list based on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-I8Z4nTDak). [Copy of the sheet I've created.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19H7mn0XfT5saWHvHeO-xDNVdNDy7aqq5V-Ryq8x80W8/edit?usp=sharing) I am happy with the functionality of the dependent drop down list, however my goal is to copy all of the data in a row from the "materials" sheet (columns B:I) that correspond to the option selected from the dependent drop down list in column E of the "crop_specific" sheet, copying this info to columns E:L. I would like to retain the functionality of the current script that clears content in column E if the selection from column D is changed, extending this to the entire row. Any help would be really appreciated. Code for the script is below.

```
    var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("crop_specific");
var wsMaterials = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("materials");
var options = wsMaterials.getRange(2,1,wsMaterials.getLastRow()-1,9).getValues();

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName == "crop_specific" && c === 4 && r>1){
    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r,5).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,5).clearDataValidations();
    }else {
    ws.getRange(r,5).clearContent();
    var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] ===val });
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[1] });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r,5);
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
    }
  }
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
    .newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInList(list)
    .setAllowInvalid(false)
    .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

- You can add some code to [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the data from `materials` sheet based on the dropdown selection.
- Remove column A since you want to copy from B to I from the `materials` sheet.
- Copy the values to the range E to L in the `crop_specific` sheet.

I have some concerns regarding the `crop_specific` sheet:

- The data is pasted in the range E-L starting from the row that was edited. So I assume you want to clear the previous content in that range, otherwise new values will overwrite part of this range.
- Column E contains a dropdown menu depending on value of column D. Maybe you want to dragdown that dropdown menu so it can be applied to the other cells in the column E.

### Solution:

```
var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("crop_specific");
var wsMaterials = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("materials");
var options = wsMaterials.getRange(2,1,wsMaterials.getLastRow()-1,9).getValues();

function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range;
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var r = activeCell.getRow();
  var c = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();
  if(wsName == "crop_specific" && c === 4 && r>1){
    if(val === ""){
      ws.getRange(r,5).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(r,5).clearDataValidations();
    }else {
    ws.getRange(r,5).clearContent();
    var filteredOptions = options.filter(function(o){ return o[0] ===val });
    var listToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(o){return o[1] });
    var cell = ws.getRange(r,5);
    applyValidationToCell(listToApply,cell);
  
    var matData = wsMaterials.getDataRange().getValues().filter(r=>r[0]===val); // new code
    matData.forEach(a => a.splice(0, 1)); // new code
    ws.getRange("E2:L" + ws.getLastRow()).clearContent(); // new code
    ws.getRange(r,5,matData.length,matData[0].length).setValues(matData); // new code
    
    }
  }
}

function applyValidationToCell(list,cell){
  
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp
    .newDataValidation()
    .requireValueInList(list)
    .setAllowInvalid(false)
    .build();

  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```